# Determine the number of subgroups of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Can we actually tell the number of subgroups of a particular cyclic group without actually listing them?

Comment: What do you know about cyclic groups? Do you know how subgroups are related to divisors of the order of the group?

Answer (score 11):

I assume you are talking of a finite cyclic group, of order $n$, say. So it's the number of divisors of $n$. If you are given the factorization
$$
n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \dots p_{k}^{e_k},
$$
where the $p_i$ are distinct primes, and the $e_i > 0$, then the number is
$$
(e_1 + 1) (e_2 + 1) \dots (e_k + 1).
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $G=\langle g \rangle $ is a finite cyclic group of order $n$, then any subgroup of $G$ has the form $S=\langle g^d\rangle$ for a divisor $d\mid n$. Different values of $d$ give different sizes so there is just one subgroup of G having a given size. Hence there are $\tau(n)$ different subgroups.
Each non-trivial subgroup of an *infinite* cyclic group has two generators, which are inverses of each other. Fixing one generator $g$ of the whole group, we can write each subgroup in the form $⟨g^n⟩$ for a unique $n ≥ 0$. So the number of subgroups is countably infinite.

Comment: why "Each non-trivial subgroup of an infinite cyclic group has two generators, which are inverses of each other?"

Comment: This is Theorem $3.2$ [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fcyclicgp.pdf&ei=DrtsVIOXHsrsO_mdgLAJ&usg=AFQjCNEvdSlk6argagB76jLNsELPMK5VKw&bvm=bv.80120444,d.ZWU).