# Number of subgroup of a group $G$ with order 2021

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

OK so here's the question I stumbled upon

> Let $G$ is a group with order 2021, how many subgroup does G have?

the thing is, I personally think that the question itself lacks additional info, so I'm not sure on how should I approach it.

So far I've been thinking that, we know $2021$ is not a prime number and that the factors of $2021$ are

$1, 43, 47, 2021$

by assuming it's cyclic, the number of subgroup is $2^k$ with $k$ is the number of distinct factors of $2021$, then we have

$2^k=2^2=4$

is this correct? any insight would really helps, thank you.

Comment: Note that $2021=43\cdot 47$, so the groups of order $2021$ are fully classified. Look up the classification of $pq$ groups.

Comment: @Alexdanut will do, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $2021 = 43 \cdot 47$ and $43 \not\mid (47-1)$ hence classification theorems give $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{2021}$. (If you like by chinese remainder theorem you also have $\mathbb{Z}_{2021} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{43} \times \mathbb{Z}_{47}$).

You reduced the problem to the studying of the number of subgroups of a cyclic group, you can find references in the following : [Determine the number of subgroups of a cyclic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481449/determine-the-number-of-subgroups-of-a-cyclic-group), [Finding all the subgroups of a cyclic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930733/finding-all-the-subgroups-of-a-cyclic-group), [Prove that the total number of subgroups of a finite cyclic group $G=\langle a \rangle$ such that $o(G)=n$ is the number of divisors of $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461174/prove-that-the-total-number-of-subgroups-of-a-finite-cyclic-group-g-langle-a)

Answer (score 2):

$|G|=43*47$

By Sylow Theorem $\exists S$ $47-Sylow$ and $\exists T$ $43-Sylow$. Lets call $n_{47}$,$n_{43}$ the number of $47-Sylow$ and $43-Sylow$.

$n_{47}= 1 mod (47)$ so $n_{47}=47\lambda+1$ and $n_{47}|(G:S)$ so appliying Langrange theorem you have that $n_{47}|43$ but $n_{47}=47\lambda+1$ so $\lambda=0$ and $n_{47}=1$

In an analogous way we have that $n_{43}=1$.

There are two unique sylows $S$ and $T$, $|G|=|S||T|$ and $S\cap T=\{1\}$ so $G\cong S\times T$ and for this abelian( Because $S$ and $T$ are) and cyclic ($43$ and $47$ coprimes), this is little redundant because clyclic implies abelian but anyway. So $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2021}$
and it has as subgoups ( whithout counting isomorphims) as divisor of 2021.

Just remember that by Lagrange theorem consecuences if $H<G$ then $|H|||G|$.
Controversly when $G$ cyclic and $|G|=n$ if $d|n$ then $\exists H<G$ such that $ |H|=d$. Don´t forget that every cyclic group $|H|=d$ is isomorphic.

So your problem is now reduced to calculate 2021 divisors number.